# Translate service dynamically Ionic 2 Angular 2 ngx-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ngx-translate

I am building an app with ionic 2 and I would like to translate some objects from the server response without storing it in a JSON file.

I´m using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core)

For example, i am receiving an object like this:

```
{
"name": ["Hello", "Hola", "Bon Jour"],
"description": ["This text is in English", "This text is in Spanish", "This text is in French"]
}
```

I would like to set the value of the string in my app depending on the language selected. How can i achieve this?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object with 3 keys (en, es, fr) and then use it to set each language using 'setTranslation'

Example:

```
translate.setTranslation('en', translations['en']);
translate.setTranslation('es', translations['es']);
translate.setTranslation('fr', translations['fr']);
```

To generate this 'translations' you can iterate over the data you have and for each item, get the translation for each language using its index in the array.

```
let data = {
  "name": ["Hello", "Hola", "Bon Jour"],
  "description": ["This text is in English", "This text is in Spanish", "This text is in French"]
}

const translations = {en: [], es: [], fr: []};
Object.keys(data).forEach( key => {
  translations['en'][key] = data[key][0];
  translations['es'][key] = data[key][1];
  translations['fr'][key] = data[key][2];
});

console.log(translations); //this will output you object ready to be used in 'setTranslation'
```

Here is a [working fiddle with this code](https://jsfiddle.net/4qjx2soc/).

**UPDATE**

You can rewrite that hard-coded piece with setTranslation in a more dynamic way

```
Object.keys(translations).forEach( key => {
  translate.setTranslation(key, translations[key]);
});
```

So you can have multiple (1..n) languages without having to repeat code.

Comment: @PabloGarcíaMiranda great! If you could, please accept my answer ;-)

Comment: Hope you can accept this answer no? @PabloGarcíaMiranda